# Unable download bot source code from Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I have published my QnA Maker and from there I have created a bot. I already tested the bot using the "Test in web Chat" function. But I need to download the code for further changes. I am not able to download it. It stays like this (shown in the image below). Can someone please help me with this?

[image: Error Image]

Comment: From Qnamaker you have created bot means? Could you please elaborate on your issue?

Comment: After publishing the QnA Maker, there was a button to create a bot which directed me to the Microsoft azure. Now I want to download the code from there and continue working on it. But I am not able to download the code.

Comment: Did you changed pre-populated QnA Auth Key & App service plan and location while creating a bot in azure.

Comment: You can check your internet connectivity and it's working fine from myside. Also verify in different browser and confirm any other blocker creating in your side.

Comment: Yes it's working fine now. I changed the network. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and I have given the solution as an answer to this question and given some extra reference probably your question will be helpful for others in the future. If it is helpful then please mark it as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following steps.

1. Did you changed the pre-populated QnA Auth Key & App service plan and location while creating a bot in azure?
2. You can check your internet connectivity and Also verify in different browsers and confirm any other blocker creating on your network side?

**Reference:**

1. [Qna Maker To Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/create-publish-knowledge-base?tabs=v1)